# HTTP status 404 JSP File (no servlet no directory fail)

Tags: java, jsp

I googled for hours before posting this.
I'm trying to reference a normal `.jsp` file into another, but I receive the HTTP Status 404 error.

This is the **index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>Hello World!</h1>
         <a href="user.jsp">LINK</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The **user.jsp** is located in /web folder (with index.jsp) and isn't a servlet.

I also created the **web.xml** file (but googling I know that there is no need to register the normal .jsp files) as the follow:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

    <display-name>test</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>user.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

The error is the same if I remove the entry `welcome-file-list`.

I'm using TomEE 1.7.4.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you detail your project's file tree? How is it in your workspace? How is it when in your delivery (war file, or exploded war). I am mostly interested in where your web folder is located, with respect to the WEB-INF folder for example.

Comment: It should work if both user.jsp and index.jsp are in same path.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved myself.
It was a problem with the TomEE service in Windows.

Comment: This answer is a non-answer, it does not clearly indicate what the problem was, nor the solution to the problem.